# how to resolve firebase deploy function error: Cloud Functions deployment requires the pay-as-you-go (Blaze) billing plan

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

(base) macbooks-mbp:functions macbook$ `firebase deploy`

```
=== Deploying to 'fir-project1-e0b25'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /Users/macbook/fireCast/functions
> tslint --project tsconfig.json
```

Running command: `npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build`

```
> functions@ build /Users/macbook/fireCast/functions
> tsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
**⚠  functions: missing required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com. Enabling now...**
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled

Error: Cloud Functions deployment requires the pay-as-you-go (Blaze) billing plan. To upgrade your project, visit the following URL:
      
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fir-project1-e0b25/usage/details

For additional information about this requirement, see Firebase FAQs:
```

Comment: Error is within `Error: Cloud Functions deployment requires the pay-as-you-go (Blaze) billing plan. To upgrade your project, visit the following URL:`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read the error message carefully, it tells you what you need to do:

> Cloud Functions deployment requires the pay-as-you-go (Blaze) billing plan. To upgrade your project, visit the following URL:
> https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fir-project1-e0b25/usage/details

Cloud Functions no longer allows you to deploy functions targeting the nodejs 10 runtime without a billing account active on the project.

See also: [Is Function Cloud in Firebase Free or Not (Cloud Functions deployment requires the pay-as-you-go (Blaze) billing plan)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62824043/is-function-cloud-in-firebase-free-or-not)

Comment: Thanks for you replying, Are there any other alternative websites where we can apply functions with out charges?

Comment: Can we still deploy functions targeting the nodejs 8?

Comment: @AlitonOliveira You can deploy by changing the node js to version 8,But node js version will expire soon warning message appear .

Comment: since what date?

Comment: I added a payment account, then selected 0 USD payment. finally Google allow i uploaded it successfully.