# Flutter: How to send push notifications even when the app is closed?

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I couldn't deploy Firebase cloud function because it is now available to only Blaze plan user which is paid now.

I want to send an automated notification whenever a new document is added in Firebase's collection.

Is there any alternative approach?

Comment: I think what you want is Firebase Cloud Messaging https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging

Comment: I want an automated push notification. Like whenever a new document is added in Firebase collection then it should notify.

Comment: acording to https://firebase.google.com/pricing cloud functions is still included in the spark plan

Comment: But deploying using nodejs is available in blaze plan now. How can I deploy function without nodejs?

Comment: Node.js 10 runtime requires Blaze plan, Node.js 8 runtime should still work in the spark plan. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: I tried bro.. it didn't work

Comment: Here's the console out with NodeJs 8.13.0 
https://i.ibb.co/M1GWWZy/image.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62824043/is-function-cloud-in-firebase-free-or-not-cloud-functions-deployment-requires-t