# 400 Billing account for project is not found. Billing must be enabled for activation of service(s)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am create API with firebase via  [this tutorial here](https://itnext.io/building-a-serverless-restful-api-with-cloud-functions-firestore-and-express-f917a305d4e6).

On I run:

```
firebase deploy
```

I get this error on the command line:

> HTTP Error: 400, Billing account for project '381106441303' is not found. Billing must be enabled for activation of service(s) 'cloudbuild.googleapis.com,containerregistry.googleapis.com' to proceed.

Please show me how to fix this problem!

Comment: Looks like [you'll have to buy a license](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#expandable-10)

Comment: @digijay but in this tutorial, the author didn't say that, and response in the following is positive.

Comment: According to what is said in the link, it was free until Aug. 2020. The turorial is from 2018.

Answer (score 76):

If you just want to finish a tutorial, just change **Node version** from 10 to 8 in **package.json**

```json
"engines": {
  "node": "8"
}
```

This will now work, but eventually after February 15, 2021 deployment of Node.js 8 functions will no longer be allowed. So, if you want to use cloud functions after this date you must be on Blaze pay-as-you-go billing plan.

Comment: Firebase will mention any methods after deploy as "deprecated" as well. Thank you for the details and work around for now!

Comment: Just as a remark, if you are using a different node version in your local machine it will reject the deploy as well. So, if it rejects it, switch to node version 8 only while deploying and it will be fine.

Comment: Error: functions.runtime value is unsupported. Valid choices are: nodejs10, nodejs12, and nodejs14.

Answer (score 29):

If you just want to test or follow the tutorial, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63951587/9322624) answer.

If you want to use at the real projects, follow these steps:

1. Enable [Billing](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing) for your projects
2. Enable [Cloud Build API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/cloudbuild.googleapis.com)
3. Enable [Container Registry API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/containerregistry.googleapis.com)

From Firebase FAQ:

> From updates on August 17, 2020, Cloud Functions for Firebase will rely on some additional paid Google services, so You have to add billing, enable Container Registry API and Cloud Storage API to use it.

See more: [Cloud Functions pricing](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#functions-pricing)

**Edit:** Following these steps automatically upgrades your Project plan to Blaze-Pay as you go. - Thanks to @Abhimanyu

Comment: Great answer. I was confused because I should be able to deploy functions without upgrading to a paid "Blaze" plan on firebase. I just needed to enable billing for my "spark" project through the above GCP billing interface. No need to go to Blaze for my demo projects.

Comment: Note: Following these steps automatically upgrades your Project plan to Blaze-Pay as you go.

Comment: This is the way to go as newer versions of the firebase sdk (since Version 9.0.0 - 14 July, 2020) no longer support node.js 8 runtime. You can't even push a new project to the cloud. You can try downgrading to the old version but don't get to used to it, It's scheduled to be pulled in early 2021.

Comment: Correct way to do this.

Comment: Surprisingly... ONLY Albert's links worked... When I attempted to add the APIs manually... I received a server error. Came back here and copy/pasted the links above... and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: No available billing accounts
There are no available billing accounts to link to this project.

Comment: this solved my problem... without upgrading to a paid "Blaze" plan

Answer (score 10):

The tutorial you're following is very old.  Cloud Functions now requires an active billing account.  You will need to add one, even if you don't expect to exceed the free allowance.

See also:

- [Is Function Cloud in Firebase Free or Not (Cloud Functions deployment requires the pay-as-you-go (Blaze) billing plan)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62824043/is-function-cloud-in-firebase-free-or-not-cloud-functions-deployment-requires-t)

Consider contacting the author of that article to tell them that they should update their article to be more accurate.

Answer (score 8):

### It works fine for me you don't have to pay I'm using firebase free tier

1st Downgrade **node version from 10 to 8** on **package.json**

```
"engines": {
"node": "8"
  }
```

2. **firebase deploy**
3. you'll get **+  Deploy complete!** message above that you'll see

   **+ functions[helloWorld(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.**
4. this **us-central**  is **my project hosted region** in your case may be differ

   prefix to this region  **[helloWorld**  is my exported function name your case it may
   differ get this information from your terminal by **firebase deploy** command
5. After  that **your hosted project link will be**

```
https://yourregion-firebaseprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/yourexportedfunctionname
```

**(exported function name) which is  helloWorld**

Comment: Error: functions.runtime value is unsupported. Valid choices are: nodejs10, nodejs12, and nodejs14.

Answer (score 4):

You can lower the node version from 10 to 8, but you should upgrade your plan to '**Blaze**' as it has the whole free plan, It will only charge you if **you pass the free plan**

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

[Full docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart?authuser=0#deploy)

Comment: thanks!  It's nice to know you can specify any of the firebase products with the `--only` switch: `hosting`, `database`, `storage`, `firestore`, `functions`

Answer (score 1):

This is a example of scheduler , but this will not work in free account . Billing must be enabled for activation of service(s) 'cloudscheduler.googleapis.com' to proceed.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import {db, notificationSentEvent, deviceData} from './init';

export const dailyDelete = functions.pubsub.schedule( '10 1 * * *' ).onRun(context => {
    console.log('At 01:10');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to firebase console
2. Go to usage and billings
3. Change plan from Free to Pay as you go

Answer (score 0):

I get an error also!

How you fix the error is: go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/your_firebase_project/usage/details website and then follow the onscreen instructions.

Then run the command in the Linux home directory on the Linux terminal:

```
firebase deploy
```

and it works!