# How to update specific object in a Field with array of objects in Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a `emojiCounter` field which is used to store an array of objects like

```
emojiCounter : [{emoji : 'haha', by : 'user1'},{emoji : 'haha', by : 'user2'}]
```

But I am trying to figure out how to update an object if a user repeatedly selects different emoji cause in that case I only have to update the `emoji` by `userName`

Answer (score 1):

Since `emojiCounter` is an array **of Objects**, you need to first read the Array, update it in the frontend then save it back to Firestore. Using the [`array-union()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) method will not work, because it is an array of Objects.

You can verify that with the following code. The objects are added, not updated.

```
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const docRef = db.collection('testSO').doc('testSO');

  const emojiCounter = [
    { emoji: 'haha', by: 'user1' },
    { emoji: 'haha', by: 'user2' },
  ];

  docRef
    .set({ emojiCounter })
    .then(() => {
      return docRef.get();
    })
    .then((doc) => {
      console.log('#1', doc.data().emojiCounter);

      return docRef.update({
        emojiCounter: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
          emoji: 'hoho',
          by: 'user1',
        }),
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      return docRef.get();
    })
    .then((doc) => {
      console.log('#2', doc.data().emojiCounter);

      return docRef.update({
        emojiCounter: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
          emoji: 'hihi',
          by: 'user2',
        }),
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      return docRef.get();
    })
    .then((doc) => {
      console.log('#3', doc.data().emojiCounter);
    });
```

---

Note that you may encounter a problem with the solution described above, because, depending on your app functions, it may imply that `user1` could change the `emoji` value of `user2`. If you want to avoid that, you should adopt another approach. For example allow the user to only update his emoji (e.g. with one emoji doc per user) and have a Cloud Function, triggered when one of those docs is updated, and which updates a central document which contains the array. You should use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) to perform the update.

---

Also, since you are using one array that contains the emojis of all users, note the [maximum size of a field value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields): 1,048,487 bytes.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer, but I decided to make `emojiCounter` a collection as it will be reliable and efficient in my way and as you said `maximum size of a field value: 1,048,487 bytes` so it would be disastrous if the number of reactors exceeds that limit

Comment: Yes, IMHO it is the good approach. I actually wrote the two last remarks in my answer with that in mind :-) Having a Cloud Function, triggered when one of those docs is updated, and which updates a central document with one or more fields may still be interesting if you need to frequently read **all** the emoji values: only one document read instead of all the collection read.

Comment: I would love to use that but since the cloud functions are no longer free, that's the problem and tbh I don't have any money to invest in G-Cloud

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62824043/is-function-cloud-in-firebase-free-or-not-cloud-functions-deployment-requires-t

Comment: yep but I don't have any card rn, maybe I will try it out in the near future